# How do I trigger a click when hovering over a element for 2 seconds, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I trigger this inline function
`onClick="showMenu('mnu_searches', event, 0, this)` 
using JQuery...if I hover over `a.menu-arrow` ? I need to trigger a click after the user has been hovering over the element for 2 seconds?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create and clear a 2 second timer, like this:

```
$("a.menu-arrow").hover(function() {
  $.data(this, "timer", setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
    $(this).click();
  }, this), 2000));
}, function() {
  clearTimeout($.data(this, "timer"));
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/9pzVQ/1/).  By using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) we're storing a timeout *per element* to avoid any issues and clear the correct timer.  The rest is just setting a 2 second timer when entering the element, and clearing it when leaving.  So if you stay for 2000ms, it fires a [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), if you leave it stops clear the timer.

Comment: hi nick, `$(this).click();` how is it triggered virtually && how is it calling its corresponding event handler without passing a event handler function as parameter to `.click()` ? can't we do this using `.trigger()` ??

Comment: @Avinash - `.click()` without parameters is a shortcut for `.trigger('click')` :)

Comment: Nice one, I've just found this quite useful for only triggering a slide down menu when the user hovers over it for at least 1 second.

Comment: This works like a charm, nevertheless, I have some dynamically created elements, so I have to use .on() instead of hover, how can I set the timer in this case ? Because it requires two functions : one for mousenter and another one for mouseleave… therefore, $(this) isn't the same between the two functions !

Answer (score 0):

use the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin or [doTimeout](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-dotimeout/examples/hoverintent/) (bit heavier)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to trigger the click-handler after two seconds. I suggest the following code:

```
$(function() {
    var timeout;

    $('a.menu-arrow').hover(function() {
        var self = this;
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $(self).click();
            timeout = null;
        });
    }, function() {
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
    });
});
```