# How do I trigger a click when hovering over a element for x seconds, using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that question have been asked, and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658814/how-do-i-trigger-a-click-when-hovering-over-a-element-for-2-seconds-using-jquer) already, but setting a timer works with hover() function.

As my element is dynamically created, it requires two different functions : one on mouseenter, and the other one on mouseleave.

Anyone have an insight on this particular need ?

PS : I know there's a plugin called hoverIntent, but I don't want to use any plugin !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $this.click();
        }, 2000)
        $this.data('clicktimer', timer)
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('clicktimer'))
    }
}, '#test');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/E5jXL/)

Comment: @A.Wolff just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
$('.myelement').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
  var element = $(this),
      ctx = null,
      timeout = 2000;

  ctx = setTimeout(function() {
     element.trigger('click');
     clearTimeout(ctx);
  }, timeout);
});
```